"fake" translated words
When studying foreign languages I occasionally encounter rare words.  These can be cross-referenced in word lists that are available from different sources to see how commonly used a word is. I have downloaded a google list of the 100,000 most common words, and another list that contains 300,000 words.   Let's take some examples that I found when studying/translating Spanish-language novels:
verídico -> veridical
"veridical" is as common as "csec" and "icuii".
169586 icuii,40237
169589 veridical,40236
169590 csec,40236
169591 productronica,40235
irrecuperable -> irrecuperable
Not in the list. That means it's less common than nonsense words:
333302 goplo,12711
333303 gopgol,12711
333304 gopgl,12711
333305 gopeel,12711
333306 gopag,12711
perfidia -> perfidy
That looks reasonable. However, from some perspective, it also seems to be a mistake sitting next to "cagr" and "minne".
92266 cagr,114286
92267 perfidy,114285
92268 minne,114276
anteceder -> antecede
Have you ever spoken or read the word "antecede"? (the browser indicates it's a misspelling)
Many more...

Is there an official linguistics term for such words?
Do you consider them to be "real words"? They seem to only appear on international website containing foreign-language translations. A native speaker would rarely (never?) choose such terms.  A native Spanish speaker would readily choose them.  This might explain their occurrence.  Even their entire existence.  You take a Spanish word, anglicize it, and voilà, task accomplished.


The average speaker very likely has never spoken, seen or heard the word ‘antecede’, but the average user of this particular site probably has. I have certainly used both ‘antecede’ and its opposite ‘postcede’ myself. This is a good illustration of the fact that your audience matters. Transparent morphology also play an important role. Any native English who knows what ‘recuperate’ or ‘reciprocate’ means will almost certainly immediately understand what ‘irrecuperable’ or ‘irreciprocably’ means (and be able to form them on the fly), even if they’d never been used before in all of history.

In Spanish, anteceder is common; the third person singular is antecede, present tense. We don't normally use the verb as much as the noun: antecedent.

There can be typos and all sorts of database issues like that. irrecuperable is generally translated as unrecoverable.  And veridico as true or real.  Bear in mind that for translation purposes you need a trustworth dictionary not some junk from the Internet. Get yourself a Harrap's two volume, for example.  Then, look up those words. Some of those aren't even words.

The only word I know is this: bad translation but I really question the validity of those lists you are working with. Are what real words? Acronyms are not real words, no. If you are really interested in literature in Spanish, this is not the way to go. They are not fake translated words; they are badly translated words.

Whatever logical mistakes you believe I made in this question (not any very serious ones), what seem undoubtable is that "veridical", "irrecuperable", "antecede" are quite rare. The existence of such terms is curious. It can give rise to questions like "Is there an official linguistics term for such words?"   A downvote about simply asking such a question seems like it is touching a nerve.

Sam, those translations are very bad, very, very bad. Your assumptions about Wikitionary are wrong. Wikitionary is not a serious research tool. It is full of mistakes. Larousse online Spanish>English: veridico:  verídico (     f verídica )
adjetivo

[cierto]   true, truthful
(figurado) [verosímil]   true-to-life, real//irrecuperable>irretrievable//anteceder>precede. And antecede is: It precedes


Now, go and try some other decent bilingual dictionaries like Collins or Harrap's and you can compare for yourself. If you are serious re lit.  you might consider buying Harrap's bilingual. The RAE (Real Academia Española) is free online monolingual one.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about linguistics and makes false assumptions re Wiktionary. translation, word usage in Spanish and how to study literature. And there is no such thing as "fake" translation. There is bad translation, mediocre translation, good translation, excellent etc.

I think @JanusBahsJacquet should take note, having written "I have certainly used .. ‘antecede’ "  certainly used antecede.   I agree with Lambie  the translation in that case is antecede -> precede,  and that antecede -> antecede is "very bad, very very bad". (see previous comment).

@Sam If the meaning is ‘come before [something] in time, order or position’, then yes, antecede would be an unusual word to use, and precede is pretty much always a better choice. If the meaning is ‘function syntactically as the antecedent to [a pro-form]’ (the sense I was referring to above, which pairs with postcede meaning ‘function syntactically as the postcedent to [a pro-form]’), then precede would be completely and utterly wrong, because precede does not have that meaning at all.

For example, in “The man who sold me the ticket wore a blue shirt”, the man antecedes (= is the antecedent to) who; and in “When it has doubled in size, remove the dough from the bowl”, the dough postcedes (= is the postcedent to) it. Using precede in the first of those statements would yield a completely different sentence that says nothing about the syntactic relations between the words in the quoted sentence, only about the order of the words. Ticket precedes wore but does not antecede it (in the linguistic sense).

@JanusBahsJacquet, you are right, there it is was me, jumping to conclusions that you would be using antecede where precede is supposed to go.  As far as the linguistics usage of the word, I am not qualified to comment.

One thing is specialized vocabulary and another is regular vocabulary. An antecedent is a well-known term in linguistics/grammar which refers to a specific thing. So, here is the formal definition: Antecedent
Definition:
An antecedent is a word, phrase, or clause referred to endophorically by another expression which precedes or follows it. https://glossary.sil.org/term/antecedent So, in one sense every antecedent precedes that to which it refers. When it follows the word, technically, the phrase or clause is a postcedent.

This gets back to the question of, what is a word? The easiest answer is to say a real word is a word that's in the dictionary, which "perfidy" is. Same for the rest of your examples.
(I'd normally suggest the venerable OED, but that's not free, and Wiktionary is.)
But maybe you don't want to take a dictionary's word for it. You could ask a native speaker, and I (as a native English-speaker) would name specific books that I've read with "perfidy" and "veridical" in them within the last year, and that I understand "antecede" and "irrecuperable" even if I haven't seen those specific forms before.
But you could also probably find a native speaker who hasn't seen "veridical" before, or hasn't studied Latin to recognize the roots of those other words. None of these are especially common, after all, as your word lists say.
Another option, then, is to say that these words are produced by general language systems that English-speakers are familiar with, and "icuii" and "cagr" aren't. English loves forming technical terms (or "inkhorn words" meant to show prestige) from Latin and Greek roots, and has various rules for doing that; "antecede" is formed through these rules. (As is the more common "antecedent", from the Latin participle instead of the Latin verb root.)
English is fine with adapting words from Spanish, too, which is why we call that particular sort of flat round bread a "tortilla", while in e.g. Mandarin they instead call it a Mòxīgē báobǐng "Mexican pancake". English overall loves taking words and word-pieces from other languages, while Mandarin doesn't.
"Gopgl", on the other hand, doesn't even follow the phonotactic rules of English (saying which sounds can go next to each other). It's probably just a typo. English-speakers pretty rapidly accepted "Google" as a new word when the search engine caught on, but probably wouldn't accept "Gopgl" the same way.
P.S. I don't think "csec" is pure nonsense—I suspect it's a technical abbreviation for "centisecond", that is, 1/100 of a second. Others of these might be OCR errors or typos.

From wikipedia: "An inkhorn term is a loanword, or a word coined from existing roots, which is deemed to be unnecessary or over-pretentious." Exactly. That reflects my original question. "is there a term.." You have almost accidentally supplied the answer, in parenthesis. But that's probably it!!

icuii ain't nonsense, too, it is the name of a video chat software for Windows.

And a quick search finds for cagr: Compound annual growth rate (CAGR)

Rather than a centisecond, csec resolves to one of the two acronyms: 1) Commercial Sexual Exploitation of Children (CSEC) 2)  Caribbean Secondary Education Certificate

The methodology is flawed as it seems the databases have put everything in and shaken it up. There are mistranslations as well. The point is not whether veridical exists in English; it's whether in most cases it would translate veridico from Spanish, which is often just true.

"The method is flawed". You are jumping to conclusions. Nothing was mistranslated since I was reading spanish source material, then observing the mere existence of words in wiktionary, and then wondering "what is the situation with these rare words."  Nothing is flawed in each of those particular steps.  I understand that the unusual words are not the main, top choice for a translation.

@Sam None of those words is rare in Spanish. Those flawed translations from Wiktionary are very misleading. I am not jumping to conclusions. Those are all words that I would use in Spanish. I've been translating from Spanish and speaking it and interpreting it for 35 years. And their English translations would not be those you found there. Go look in a decent, real bilingual dictionary.

I'm realizing my other answer focused exclusively on "are these real words", so to address the other part:

Is there an official linguistics term for such words?

These are sometimes called inkhorn words: fancy words used to show off the speaker/writer/translator's skill with the language, even when a simpler word would do just as well. (An "inkhorn" was an inkwell made out of animal horn: something not necessary for your average person, but valuable to a scholar who's constantly using ink and needs a durable way to hold it. So an "inkhorn word" is a word used specifically by pretentious scholars, while everyone else is content with their normal, everyday vocabulary.)
More formally, though, these could be called prestige loans. Languages borrow words ("loanwords") from other languages for all sorts of reasons, and the most common one is necessity: English-speakers had no word for potatoes before contact with the Americas (since they aren't native to Europe), but various American languages did, so English borrowed "potato" from there.
Sometimes, though, languages borrow words even when they have perfectly good existing words of their own—because using a borrowed term conveys prestige for one reason or another. English has a perfectly good word "cow" inherited from Anglo-Saxon, but we also borrowed "beef" from Norman French and "bovine" from Latin for reasons of prestige.

There is flawed logic here. The database may contain all sorts of Spanish words but supposed translation provided by the OP are "off". veridico, for example, is not translated as viridical.  And also, it seems it contains a lot of acronyms.

@Lambie the dictionary is Wiktionary. Where I discover "veridical" as a translation of veridico.  Apparently this is an English word.  It's rarity is likely not debated. The explanation, I believe, is this answer, it's an inkhorn term. The database is just a web scrape of millions of pages and then counted.  So, acronyms.

Wikitionary is just a bunch of words a bunch of people put up there any old way. It is not a serious, quality lexicologist dictionary. Of course, veridical is a word. That is not the point. The point is that in Spanish it is used a LOT and the places where it is used in English as veridical is not usual; it is quasi-archaic.  There are tons of words like that between the two languages, which is why you need to use a decent bilingual dictionary. Also, to study literary uses, you read the books, yellow in what you don't know and then use a good dictionary. Also, a monolingual Spanish one.

You have to internatize an L2 little by little. It's not a numbers game.
